# Python: Class substantiation

Tags: class, python-2.7

I want to be able to open up a file like this:

> 42.65 42.75
>
> -72.85 -72.75
>
> TW52 42.73 -72.84 2.1
>
> TW98 42.727 -72.81 2.9
>
> TW2a  42.688 -72.82 1.1
>
> CT4b  42.715 -72.78 2.4
>
> CT5c  42.682 -72.779 2.41

I want to do this using a class, but I am not sure how I would approach it... so far I have this

```
class Homework:

    fname = raw_input("Enter the name of the input file ==> ")
    in_file = open(fname, "r")

    def __init__(self, in_file):
            self.in_file[0] = pID
            self.in_file[1] = latitude
            self.in_file[2] = longitude
            self.in_file[3] = distance

    def displayFile(self):
        print self.in_file[0], self.in_file[1], self.in_file[2], self.in_file[3]

x = Homework()
print x.displayFile()
```

The first two lines, I want to be able to store them somewhere for later usage, and then the remainder into pID, latitude, longitude, and distance.

I want to be able to store the 0th index: TW52 to an object like pID and store the 1st index: 42.73 to latitude, -72.84 to longitude, and 2.1 to distance.
How would I be able to do this?
I get the error where it tells me that **init** takes exactly 2 arguments when only 1 is given!
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that `__init__` takes two arguments, but you only gave it one (`self` is passed automatically). You never passed anything for the `in_file` argument:

```
in_file = open(filename, "r")

x = Homework(in_file)
x.displayFile()

in_file.close()
```

I suggest you read through a Python tutorial before jumping into classes. You seem to be assigning variables backwards.

Comment: I'm confused at how you said I was assigning variables backwards... I was referencing a guide from learnpython.org and this was like the 'template' that it said to use. 
When I did x = Homework(), I simply assigned a class object to a variable, but if I assigned a parameter to it like in_file, it would not be defined because it is not inside the Class.
Sorry if I'm confusing!